# Presetting a path for Excel's GetOpenFilename from Word VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Using a master macro in a MS-Word template file (as originally it is a *dotm).  I need to open an Excel file (each time a different one with different paths, at user choice).

I am using a filepicker, to let the user select the required file.

It always opens filepicker at "MyDocument" default folder path.

This is my MS-Word Master code:

```vb
'**********************************************
Set Excel_Tool = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    
'Set  dialog box file filter
ID_Finfo = "Excel Files (*.xlsx; *.xls), *xlsx;*.xls"
'Set  dialog box caption title
Title = "Select an ID-file to open"
'Get  Filename
Excel_Path_Name = Excel_Tool.Application.GetOpenFilename(ID_Finfo, , Title, , False)

If Excel_Path_Name = "" Or Excel_Path_Name = "False" Then
    Response = msgbox("It Seems You Submitted a NOT VALID file/path data..." & vbCrLf & "            Pay More Attention, Please !!!" & vbCrLf & "        So, What Would You Like to Do, Now?       ", vbRetryCancel + vbExclamation)
    If Response = vbRetry Then
        Unload Me
        Call Open_ID_File_Form
    Else
        Unload Me
    End If
End If
'**********************************************
```

The DIM statements are correct; indeed it opens a "MyDoc" default browsing filepicker window.

I tried two ways:

```vb
Sub EXCEL_by_EXCEL_File_Open_PROVA_WEB()

Dim fileName

ChDrive "C:"
ChDir "C:\MY OWN Program files\test_excel opening"
Set Excel_Tool = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

fileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm), *xlsx;*.xls;*xlsm")

If fileName <> "False" Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Workbooks.Open fileName, Format:=2
End If

End Sub
```

This works if launched in Excel, but it fails (MyDoc as default folder) if called in Word.

I tried to "trick the system" by copying the target file path inside clipboard and then asking the user to paste it on filepicker path field:

```vb
Def_Excel_Path_Name = ActiveDocument.Path & "\"

' this line sets the dir as the same of the word doc
' moving current WORD file path text to clipboard in order to allow  USER to workaround Word bug about "myDoc" as default folder

Dim Carrier As New DataObject
Carrier.SetText Def_Excel_Path_Name
Carrier.PutInClipboard

' now USER can paste it to address field on file picker window, in order to go straight to source document folder
```

It is copying folder-path on the clipboard but, when Master macro opens filepicker and I try to paste clipboard text (the source path) inside dedicated path field, nothing copied.

If I check clipboard content, I find a couple of question marks  --> "??"

Comment: Try using the file open dialog instead as it takes various arguments, including filename which can be used to set the initial path: See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.dialogs); [argument list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/Concepts/Controls-DialogBoxes-Forms/built-in-dialog-box-argument-lists); and [code example](https://www.codevba.com/excel/dialogs.htm#.ZFecQKDMJmM)

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, but the data/links you supplied and which I browsed so far, are all related to Excel Master macros (and indeed they work perfect in such environment, as in my first example). On th eopposite side, my target is to open a filepicker selector (in order to get an excel file path) but starting (and returning it) to a Word Master macro generated and managed call. Thanks

Comment: And that will also work when you automate Excel from Word.

Answer (score 0):

just use the "**[Excel.Application.DefaultFilePath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.defaultfilepath)**" property to set where that you want the filepicker box to show default:

Add this line in your first code snippet :

```vb
　　Excel_Tool.Application.DefaultFilePath = Def_Excel_Path_Name
```

then Try it:

```vb
    Dim Excel_Tool As Object, Def_Excel_Path_Name As String, ID_Finfo As String, Title As String, Excel_Path_Name As Variant, Response As VbMsgBoxResult
    
    Set Excel_Tool = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    
    'Def_Excel_Path_Name = where to start
    Def_Excel_Path_Name = "w:\" 'set what you want to here
    Excel_Tool.Application.DefaultFilePath = Def_Excel_Path_Name
    'VBA.ChDir Def_Excel_Path_Name 'this just to apply the call side which as Word VBA NOT Excel Application
    
'    Excel_Tool.Quit 'if not quit after using or if without next line, this showing will be the last time's setting until restarting excel application object to apply.
    Set Excel_Tool = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 'restart excel.application object.this will create just one excel instance.
    
'Set  dialog box file filter
    ID_Finfo = "Excel Files (*.xlsx; *.xls), *xlsx;*.xls"
'Set  dialog box caption title
    Title = "Select an ID-file to open"
'Get  Filename
   Excel_Path_Name = Excel_Tool.Application.GetOpenFilename(ID_Finfo, , Title, , False)


If Excel_Path_Name = "" Or Excel_Path_Name = "False" Then
        Response = MsgBox("It Seems You Submitted a NOT VALID file/path data..." & vbCrLf & "            Pay More Attention, Please !!!" & vbCrLf & "        So, What Would You Like to Do, Now?       ", vbRetryCancel + vbExclamation)
        If Response = vbRetry Then
            Unload Me
            Call Open_ID_File_Form
        Else
            Unload Me
        End If
    End If

    Excel_Tool.Quit ' if without this , the setting of DefaultFilePath before would not apply properly
```

if you want to use **clipboard** function [try this instead](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2015/1/13/how-to-use-vba-code-to-copy-text-to-the-clipboard):

```vb
Function ClipboardPutIn(Optional StoreText As String) As String 'https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2015/1/13/how-to-use-vba-code-to-copy-text-to-the-clipboard
'PURPOSE: Read/Write to Clipboard
'Source: ExcelHero.com (Daniel Ferry)

Dim x As Variant

'Store as variant for 64-bit VBA support
  x = StoreText

'Create HTMLFile Object
  With CreateObject("htmlfile")
    DoEvents
    With .parentWindow.clipboardData
      Select Case True
        Case Len(StoreText)
          'Write to the clipboard
            .setData "text", x
        Case Else
          'Read from the clipboard (no variable passed through)
            ClipboardPutIn = .GetData("text")
      End Select
    End With
  End With

End Function
```